# How to implement rating in ionic 3?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

How do I create 5 star rating in ionic 3, I visited https://github.com/andrucz/ionic2-rating but it is not working. Also read some tutorial but not found anything clean and clear for ionic 3.
Just for clear, I want to get rating value and display rating.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thankyou

Comment: what about this https://github.com/melwinVincent/ionic3-star-rating?

Comment: Thanks working on it.

Comment: I am getting 
ERROR Error: "Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'rating' since it isn't a known property of 'ionic3-star-rating'.
1. If 'ionic3-star-rating' is an Angular component and it has 'rating' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'ionic3-star-rating' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

and 3rd step is not clear for me

Comment: You need to import module to your app module

Comment: Did you follow step-2?

Comment: Now it's working thanks @OmurbekKadyrbekov, but how do I get value in ts file step 3rd is not clear for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic3-star-rating

Use [github.com/melwinVincent/ionic3-star-rating](http://github.com/melwinVincent/ionic3-star-rating) npm package.

Step 1. Add the ionic3-star-rating component in your page (parent component) as follows

```
<ionic3-star-rating 
    activeIcon = "ios-star"
    defaultIcon = "ios-star-outline"
    activeColor = "#488aff" 
    defaultColor = "#f4f4f4"
    readonly="false"
    [rating]="3">
</ionic3-star-rating>
```

Step 2.
You have to import the StarRatingModule in the module.ts of your parent component as follows

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPageModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { ParentPage } from './parent';
import { StarRatingModule } from 'ionic3-star-rating';

@NgModule({
declarations: [
    ParentPage,
],
imports: [
    StarRatingModule,
    IonicPageModule.forChild(ParentPage),
],
})
export class ParentPageModule {}
```

Step 3.
To get the changed rating in the parent component,
You need to use `events` from ionic package.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Events } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-about',
  templateUrl: 'about.html'
})
export class AboutPage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,
  public events: Events) {
     events.subscribe('star-rating:changed', (starRating) => {console.log(starRating)});
  }

}
```

Comment: Working nice but on the console it will showing NaN why ?

Comment: @Rajat.r2 check this demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic3-star-rating

Comment: I did the same and in your demo stackblitz.com/edit/ionic3-star-rating  it is also showing NaN ?
First time it will show 4 because default value of rating is 4

Comment: The package has been upgraded to support multiple usage of ionic3-star-rating component in the same parent page. Latest version supports the usage in <form> component as well. You can also configure the font-size of the icons now. 
Upgrade the component by running the command
**npm install ionic3-star-rating@2.0.0**.

Comment: so does it support values like 3.2 ?

Comment: @OmurbekKadyrbekov I use this code but it gives me error like compiler.js:486 Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
'ionic3-star-rating' is not a known element:
1. If 'ionic3-star-rating' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'ionic3-star-rating' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
Can you help me to solve this. I use 2.1.0 version of this component

Comment: @user11469878 Probably you did not add it to modules. If you share your code, I will help you.

Comment: @OmurbekKadyrbekov 
I add it to as module in main module file.
`
import { StarRatingModule } from 'ionic3-star-rating'; and then in  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    StarRatingModule]
`
but still it gives that error